# How to read response body data from another URL using javascript?

Tags: javascript, response, alert

How can i read response body data from another url.

Im try to read some website url response body data to my site . (as javascript alert or whatever)

" https://example.com/export/file "

Answer (score 0):

If you want to read web resources using plain old Javascript, you can use XMLHttpRequests. For more info, read [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest)

What you are trying to do is referred to as making an "AJAX" call. If you want other ways of doing it, or want to use other libraries (e.g. JQuery) to get this info, you can google "AJAX with ...." to help get more info

Comment: XMLHttpRequests not working for sites like google.com. any solution for it?

Comment: Not if you're using a web browser and want to retrieve data from arbitrary sites. [`XMLHttpRequest` will only work within the same domain, protocol, and port, or if the target site sends an `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header that allows your site to read it.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS)